# Principal bundle Isomorphism between the Hopf fibration and the orthornomal frame bundle of the tautological line bundle.

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, fiber-bundles

As usual, the Hopf fibration $S^3\to \mathbb{C}P^1$ is a principal $S^1$  bundle. Now, since we can embed the tautological complex line bundle $L$ in the trivial bundle $\mathbb{C}P^1 \times \mathbb{C}^2$ (by defining the elements of $L$ to be $([z_1:z_2],l)\in \mathbb{C}P^1 \times \mathbb{C}^2$ with $l\in [z_1:z_2]$), it inherits a hermitian metric and we can therefore talk about the orthonormal frame bundle associated with $L$. Now, I want to show that $S^3$ is isomorphic to this orthonormal frame bundle. I can easily see that the $S^3$ has a natural $U(1)$ action as $U(1)\cong S^1$, but cannot come up with an explicit mapping between them.

Comment: The main point here is to show that $L$ can be realized as the associated bundle corresponding to the standard representation of $U(1)$ on $\mathbb C$. Having this, the result is more or less a tautology. How this is done most easily depends a bit on how you view the Hopf fibration as a principal bundle.

Comment: Call the Hopf map $\pi$ and use $F$ the frame bundle of $L$.  Then the map $S^3\rightarrow F$ is $p\mapsto (\pi(p),p)$ where we are using the usual identification of $S^2$ and $\mathbb{C}P^1$.